# Implementing a back button for multiple frames in a scene in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, button

I have a Flash document with two scenes. On Scene 1, I have a chart with several buttons; it’s a family tree, and each button directs you to scene 2, which is that person’s personal page on an individual frame in scene 2. In scene 2, I have a back button that directs you back to the chart in scene 1.

My problem is that the back button which appears across all the frames in scene 2, via extending the keyframe to include all the frames, only works on frame 1 not on the rest of the frames. When I click on it on frame 1 in scene 2, it goes back to scene 1, frame 1, like it should, but if I’m on frame 2 (scene 2) and click, nothing happens.

```
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 1");
```

Comment: I’ll migrate this to [so] as it seems to be answerable as it stands. Note though that your example code seems to be incomplete and you have better chances of getting an answers with a complete [mcve].